# Find the next digit in four given sequences

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Find the next digit in each of these four sequences:

```
7 8 8 8 8 ...
3 4 5 2 5 ...
2 1 2 1 2 ...
1 1 9 6 3 ...
```

Comment: Are the four sequences related? If not, there are too many possible answers, see OEIS

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: This is frustrating when one tries to find logical solution but actually this is about some constants.

Comment: All digit sequences are some constant. Stop trying to be so rational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers are

> 5, 5, 4, 8

Explanation, those series go 2 by 2:

> Sequences are made by separing odd position digits and even position digits of e and pi

Sequence 3 with sequence 1

> One digit out of 2 of number e: 2,71828...  Third sequence starts with integer part 2

Sequence 2 with sequence 4

> One digit out of 2 of number pi: 3,14159... Second sequence starts with integer part 3